# Why are points missing in zooming in on a tweened line?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to make a two-line chart in d3.js. I have added a zoom on one axis only. Once I added a transition (tween), the zoom is being a bit weird. If I zoom in enough, certain points will be missing. This is not happening when the tween is off. The faulty behavior is much more prominent when there are many more points. Keep zooming in and try here: https://jsfiddle.net/cvm43f5y/

Let me know what am I doing wrong. Thank you.

```
let d3svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("height", "500")
  .attr("width", "500");
d3svg.selectAll("g").remove();

data1 = [
    {"time": 0.1, "value":12},
  {"time": 0.2, "value":15},
  {"time": 0.3, "value":16},
  {"time": 0.4, "value":18},
  {"time": 0.5, "value":11},
  {"time": 0.6, "value":13},
  {"time": 0.7, "value":21},
  {"time": 0.8, "value":20},
]

data2 = [
    {"time": 0.9, "value":8},
  {"time": 1.0, "value":9},
  {"time": 1.2, "value":7},
  {"time": 1.3, "value":8},
  {"time": 1.4, "value":9},
  {"time": 1.5, "value":12},
  {"time": 1.6, "value":11},
  {"time": 1.7, "value":6},
]


var margin = {
  top: 20,
  right: 20,
  bottom: 50,
  left: 60
};
var width = +d3svg.attr('width') - margin.left - margin.right;
var height = +d3svg.attr('height') - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var xScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, width]);
var yScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

var line = d3.line()
.x(function(d) {
  return xScale(d.time)
})
.y(function(d) {
  return yScale(d.value)
});

let timeMax = d3.max(data2, d => d.time);
xScale.domain([0, timeMax]);
yScale.domain(d3.extent(data1, function(d) {
  return d.value;
}));

var g = d3svg.append('g')
.attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');

var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(xScale)
.ticks(5)

g.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'axis axis-x')
  .attr('transform', 'translate(0,' + height + ')')
  .call(xAxis);

var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(yScale)
.tickFormat(d3.format('.4f'));

g.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'axis axis-y')
  .call(yAxis);

g.append('path')
  .datum(data1)
  .attr('fill', 'none')
  .attr('class', 'line line-media')
  .attr('stroke-linejoin', 'round')
  .attr('stroke-linecap', 'round')
  .attr('stroke-width', 1.5)
  .attr("stroke", "#16a085")
//.attr('d', line);
g.selectAll("path.line-media").datum(data1).attr('d', line).call(transition)

g.append('path')
  .datum(data2)
  .attr('fill', 'none')
  .attr('class', 'line line-drug')
  .attr('stroke-linejoin', 'round')
  .attr('stroke-linecap', 'round')
  .attr('stroke-width', 1.5)
  .attr("stroke", "#2e4053")
//.attr('d', line);
g.selectAll("path.line-drug").datum(data2).attr('d', line).call(transition)

let zoom = d3.zoom();
zoom.on("zoom", function(){
  let newYScale = d3.event.transform.rescaleY(yScale)
  yAxis.scale(newYScale);
  d3.select(".axis-y").call(yAxis);

  line = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) {
    return xScale(d.time)
  })
    .y(function(d) {
    return newYScale(d.value)
  });

  g.selectAll("path.line").attr("d", line);
})
d3svg.call(zoom);

function transition(path) {
  path.transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .attrTween("stroke-dasharray", tweenDash);
}
function tweenDash() {
  var l = this.getTotalLength(),
      i = d3.interpolateString("0," + l, l + "," + l);
  return function (t) { return i(t); };
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you zoom in your path gets very big and having set a `stroke-dasharray` means it gets dashed.

Solution remove the `stroke-dasharray` at the end of the transition.

```
function transition(path) {
  path.transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .attrTween("stroke-dasharray", tweenDash)
    .on("end", function () { d3.select(this).attr("stroke-dasharray", null); });
}
```

You can add the `transition` call directly to the `path` construction

```
g.append('path')
  .datum(data1)
  .attr('fill', 'none')
  .attr('class', 'line line-media')
  .attr('stroke-linejoin', 'round')
  .attr('stroke-linecap', 'round')
  .attr('stroke-width', 1.5)
  .attr("stroke", "#16a085")
  .attr('d', line)
  .call(transition);
```

Simplify `tweenDash`

```
function tweenDash() {
  var l = this.getTotalLength();
  return d3.interpolateString("0," + l, l + "," + l);
}
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you so much. It fixed it.